# Scale transform on iCarousel showing area off-screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, cgaffinetransform, icarousel

I have an `iCarousel` which contains some elements which are below the bottom of the screen (i.e. they can be scrolled to).

I’m performing an animation where I apply a `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` to that `UIScrollView`, and upon doing so, the view shrinks, but where the rest of the view would be, nothing is drawn. I understand that this is due to the fact that the area is off-screen when the transform is made, but I’m wondering how I can fix this.

Ideally, when I begin the transform, it should draw the entire contents of carousel, including that which is off-screen, then perform the scale animation meaning some of that area that was previously off-screen is shown.

In the image here, the topmost slice shows the images at the bottom of the screen, cut-off, then the second image shows them when transformed, no longer at the bottom of the screen, but still cut-off at that position. I’d like the rest of those images to become visible when scaling the view down.

How might I go about this?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you're doing is shrinking the scroll view, instead of shrinking the content that the scroll view is displaying.

I suggest using the zoom feature of the UIScrollView to shrink the content. In order for this to work, all of the content must be contained in a single view. Since it appears that you have multiple images (as multiple UIImageViews), the first thing you would need to do is create a generic UIView and add all of the UIImageViews as subviews of the generic view.

Then, to use the zoom feature of the scroll view, you will need to do the following.

- declare that the view controller conforms to the
  `<UIScrollViewDelegate>` protocol
- return the view to be zoomed from the `viewForZoomingInScrollView`
  method
- set the initial zoom parameters, contentSize, and delegate for the
  scroll view
- when adjusting the zoom level, make sure that the new zoom level is
  valid

That last point simply means that when you change the `zoomScale`, the old zoomScale and the new zoomScale must both be between the `minimumZoomScale` and the `maximumZoomScale`.

In the sample code below, I have a scroll view and a single `UIImageView` that's being zoomed and scrolled. For testing, I have a couple buttons that change the zoom level.  Note that after adjusting the zoom level, I disable zooming (preventing the user from changing the zoom level) by setting both the minimum and maximum zoom scales to the current zoom scale.

```
@interface MainViewController () <UIScrollViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect frame = CGRectZero;

    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SomeImage"];
    frame.size = self.imageView.image.size;
    self.imageView.frame = frame;

    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0;
    self.scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = frame.size;
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return( self.imageView );
}

- (void)adjustZoomLevel:(CGFloat)newZoom
{
    if ( newZoom > self.scrollView.zoomScale )
    {
        self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = newZoom;
        [self.scrollView setZoomScale:newZoom animated:YES];
        self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = newZoom;
    }
    else
    {
        self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = newZoom;
        [self.scrollView setZoomScale:newZoom animated:YES];
        self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = newZoom;
    }
}

- (IBAction)zoomInButtonPressed
{
    [self adjustZoomLevel:self.scrollView.zoomScale * 1.25];
}

- (IBAction)zoomOutButtonPressed
{
    [self adjustZoomLevel:self.scrollView.zoomScale * 0.80];
}

@end
```

Comment: I’m shrinking each of the views inside the scroll view in turn, not the scroll view itself, but the zooming sounds interesting, I’ll try that. I’m actually using iCarousel now, so hopefully it’ll work there, too.

Comment: Alas, iCarousel has no zooming options, so I think I will need to use the transform.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I needed to do was turn `clipsToBounds` off for the `scrollView` instances inside the carousel. D’oh!